# Find index range of a sequence in dataframe column

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries:

```
            Sales
2018-01-01  66.65
2018-01-02  66.68
2018-01-03  65.87
2018-01-04  66.79
2018-01-05  67.97
2018-01-06  96.92
2018-01-07  96.90
2018-01-08  96.90
2018-01-09  96.38
2018-01-10  95.57
```

Given an arbitrary sequence of values, let's say `[66.79,67.97,96.92,96.90]`, how could I obtain the corresponding indices, for example: `[2018-01-04, 2018-01-05,2018-01-06,2018-01-07]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`pandas.Series.isin`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter the column `Sales` then [**`pandas.DataFrame.index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html?highlight=index#pandas.DataFrame.index) to return the row labels (aka index, dates in your `df`) and finally [**`pandas.Series.to_list`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html?highlight=to_list#pandas.Series.to_list) to build a list :

```
vals = [66.79,67.97,96.92,96.90]

result = df[df['Sales'].isin(vals)].index.to_list()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(result)
['2018-01-04', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08']
```